# Python tkinter image not showing up

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have a problem with Python tkinter images. Have a brief look at a code bellow, and then read the rest. My problem is that image from `self.file_with_puzzle()` is not showing up. However when I put just the (testing) code from that class in between `self.file_with_puzzle()` and `self.g.mainloop()` it is working (As shown in the code). My guess is that it has sth to do with `mainloop()` but as I am a beginner programmer and there is no any error in Python Shell, I have no idea what the problem is.
**There are also some restrictions**, `mainloop()` **has** to be in `__init__()`, but could be put earlier or later, but still within the `__init__()`. (And is there so when you launch the file outside the idle it won't immediately close). Also no calling anything else besides `MyClass()` at the end of code.

```
import tkinter, math, random

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.g = tkinter.Canvas(width=800,height=800)
        self.g.pack()

        #self.game_board() Not needed right now, that's why it is commented
        #self.game_objects() Same as above
        self.file_with_puzzle()
        #thing bellow works but not wanted, just to show that it works this way
        """
        picture = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='photo.jpg')
        self.g.create_image(100,100, image=picture)
        """ 
        self.g.mainloop() # mainloop has to be in __init__()

        .
        .
        .

    """ FILE SECTION (5) """

    def file_with_puzzle(self):
        .
        .
        .
        # code here is just simple version for testing, otherwise it's more complex
        picture = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='photo.jpg')
        self.g.create_image(100,100, image=picture)

    """ END (5) """

MyClass()
#can call only MyClass() nothing else here
```

Comment: @Kevin Yes, the same problem. I didn't know it works this way. I couldn't find such question /answer. Well, thank you. Should we delete this question then ?